# Exclude records based off particular string text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sample data, and I need to exclude any records that contain Room 2 or above within the Address.

The following works:

```
select * from #temp
where Address not like '%Room 2%' and Address not like '%Room 3%' and Address not like '%Room 4%'
```

But if a record with Room 5 comes along, it isn't going to work without actually remembering to maintain the query. Is there a way to get around this?

```
Create table #temp
(
    ID int,
    Address varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp
(
    ID,
    Address
)
select
    1,
    '50 High Street'
union all
select
    2,
    '101 Worth Street'
union all
select
    3,
    'Room 1, 500 Canal Street'
union all
select
    4,
    'Room 2, 974 White Street'
union all
select
    5,
    '53 Grand Street'
union all
select
    6,
    'Room 3, 87 Walker Street'
union all
select
    7,
    '30 Church Street'
union all
select
    8,
    'Room 4 - 1 Spring Street'
union all
select
    9,
    '40 Beach Street'
union all
select
    10,
    '50 Henry Street'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a little hard to do with `like`, but one method is:

```
select *
from #temp
where not (Address like 'Room 1[0-9]%' or
           Address like 'Room [2-9]%'
          )
```

That is, the address does not have Room with 1 followed by a digit or Room followed by 2-9.